# Why does my function suddenly stop?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

This is the troubling code piece:

```
    private void CodesListSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_doNothing) return;
        _drawMarker = false;
        _doNothing = true;
        _entitiesList.SelectedItems[0].Selected = false;
        _doNothing = false;
        Game.CurrentItem = Item.GetItemByCodeId(_codesList.SelectedIndices[0]);
    }

    private bool _doNothing;

    private void EntitiesListSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_doNothing) return;
        _drawMarker = false;
        _doNothing = true;
        _codesList.SelectedItems[0].Selected = false;
        _doNothing = false;
        Game.CurrentItem = Item.GetItemByEntityId(_entitiesList.SelectedIndices[0]);
    }
```

Basically I have two listViews, _codesList and _entitiesList, both have one item. What I want them to do is when one is selected, the other should deselect itself. To prevent the event of being triggered when changing the selected index from the respective other list to false I have my variable _doNothing, which is set to false at the start.

Now what happens when I select the first item (lets say in _entitiesList) is that it goes as far as to _codesList.SelectedItems[0].Selected = false; then it suddenly drops out of the function, not even triggering the event for the other and does completely other unrelated stuff and never ever goes back to finishing this function. I've stepped through it with debugging times and times again and it's always the same. This means _doNothing is never set to false again, thus all further event calls fail immediately ofcause...

Wtf is happening?

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown box for CLR exceptions.  Set the project's Target Platform setting to AnyCPU if you debug on a machine with a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: I think your SelectedItems collection is empty or null and accessing it on [0] raise an exception. If ListView has an item inside, it doesn't mean that it should be selected. Just guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to access SelectedItems[0] when SelectedItems.Count == 0 throws an exception. ("Index Out Of Range" or something similar.) You must not have configured your debugger to stop when an exception is thrown, so you never find out about it. The dropping out of the function and the other unrelated stuff that it does are probably all part of the regular course of things when an exception is thrown. A hint for this should be the appearance of an $exception entry in the `locals` view of the debugger.

What to do: first of all, make sure you have configured visual studio to always stop on all exceptions. (Some people refrain from doing this because then it starts stopping all over the place, but I think that's not a reason not to do it; it is a reason to go to each one of those places and fix the bugs.) Secondly, use the `Clear()` method of the `SelectedItems` collection, it does not throw an exception when the collection happens to be already empty.

Comment: this is the thing that bugs me most. I have it configured to always stop at exceptions, and usually it does just that (hell if I manually throw an exception there and never catch it it stops instantly). The thing that bugs me most is that it actually seems to run along just fine after this, meaning for example my tick() event from the clock thingy is the next thing that gets shown while stepping through the code.

Comment: GUIs are event-driven systems, so almost everything that happens in a GUI happens as a result of an event which originated from within Operating System (or, in the case of dotnet, Framework) code. So, if the debugger does not stop at the exception, and your code does not catch the exception, then the exception bubbles up to the framework, and since the framework does not have anything to do with it, it just ignores it. Then, when the next event occurs, it is business as usual, as if no exception was ever thrown. So, I would expect that behavior.

Comment: What is *really* puzzling is why does Visual Studio not stop when the exception is thrown.  Have you checked for the presence of the $exception entry in the "Locals" or "Auto" window of the debugger right after the offending instruction? Is it there?

Comment: Nope, it's nowhere to be found, but an exception is indeed being thrown and I could catch it no problem using a try..finally. It still bugs me that VS refuses to stop and show the exception when its unhandled, but maybe this is all just because this is a kinda specific kind ofform (its actually a form started up from inside an XNA game, so maybethere's so manydifferent threads that VS can't keep track of the exception or something in this scope, maybe its not keeping track of the threads UnhandledExpectionHandler or something, which it may not have as I didnt start the formviaApplication.Run).

Comment: Oh, that sounds like a very evil situation. When the tool is not doing its job, that's baaaad. I hope you can find some way to overcome this situation, otherwise debugging will be a nightmare, as I am sure you have already found out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the code you are looking at while debugging is not the code that was actually compiled.  Try doing a build -> clean, and then a complete rebuild (Ctrl+Shift+B in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0):

SelectedItems[0] doesn't exist (returns null) until an item is selected. When your code attempts to set the Selected property on a null value, it's throwing an exception.

It would be better to use a Binding to set the Items[0].Selected value to the inverse of the Items[0].Selected in the other ListView.